# Runtime GL_VERSION doesn't match glxinfo?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, cmake, glfw

I need to use Tessellation in OpenGL, which means that my OpenGL version need to be 4.0 or upper. I get my OpenGL version with `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` in terminal. Output shows in the following:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 520.61.05
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 520.61.05
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 520.61.05
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

It shows apparently that My OpenGL version is 4.6.0. But when I run the code:

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```

I get:

```
3.3.0 NVIDIA 520.61.05
```

The reason that why I find this mismatch is that I get `segmentation fault` when I call the function:

```
void glPatchParameteri(GLenum pname​​, GLint value​​);
```

My `GLAD` is generated with the expected version `4.6.0`.
And my `CMakeLists.txt` is edited as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(visualization_displacement_map)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
file(GLOB project_file glad.c main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_file} utility/init_func.cpp utility/callback_func.cpp utility/class/SoarCamera.cpp utility/class/SoarCamera.h program/program_test.cpp utility/class/Shader.cpp utility/class/Shader.h utility/debug_func.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TARGET_LIB}
        -lglfw
        -lGL
        -lm
        -lXrandr
        -lXi
        -lX11
        -lXxf86vm
        -lpthread
        -ldl
        -lXinerama
        -lXcursor
        )
```

Why does this mismatch happen?

Comment: Sounds like your context is probably a 3.3 context. How are you creating your OpenGL context?

Comment: @fordcars I mistakenly set my `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION` to 3.3 in runtime. Everything goes well since I changed it to 4.6. Thank you very much for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which context are you requesting at runtime? Almost sounds like you are requesting a 3.3 context? (or the windowing lib you're using is).

in glut:

```cpp
glutInitContextVersion( 3, 3 );
glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
```

in glfw:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

in sdl:

```cpp
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot！I make a mistake that I copy the initialization part of OpenGL code from my previous project. Since I used to use 3.3 version, I explicitly set the `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION` to 3.3. Every goes correctly since I chanced it to 4.6!